# New to jQuery - why isn't this working?

Tags: jquery, html

This is really basic so sorry in advance for having to ask for help :o

I've setup a simple page to play with jQuery but I can't get a simple show/hide function to work.

Here's my code..

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Javascript/jQuery</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div p").hide();
    });

    $("show").click(function(){
        $("div p").show()
    });

    $("hide").click(function(){
        $("div p").hide()
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id='hide'>Click to hide the text</button>
    <button id='show'>Click to show the text</button>
     <div><p>you can't see me!</p></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Chromes developer tools give no error so im not sure where to look.

The text is initially hidden at first but the show and hide buttons do nothing.

Comment: use # for id and . to class selectors. And a tip:  if you use jQuery CDN (calling from external jQuery script like this : <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>) in production, you may suffer with a decrease in the speed of the page loading

Comment: @EricMartins What do you mean ? Using CDN scripts is usually faster and gentler for caches than using your own scripts.

Comment: @dystroy Frequently I got errors because the host of those scripts is taking too long to respond, but yes is faster most of the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$("show").click(function(){
```

with

```
$("#show").click(function(){
```

so that jQuery looks for the element with id `show` (and of course the same for `$("hide")`).

Comment: There must be something wrong with my page as thats not working either.

    $("#show").click(function(){
     $("div p").show()
    });

Ah nvm - I placed the code inside of my .ready call and it worked!